# Чтение массива записей из типизированного файла

Tags: delphi, файлы, pascal

Мне нужно прочитать массив записей (состоит из одной строки и 6 цифр) из типизированного файла и записать в таблицу (`StringGrid`). В типизированном файле данные находятся каждое значение на новой строчке. В таблицу выводится какая-то каша из мусора. С индексацией всё в порядке.

```
procedure TMainForm.N3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    TypeFile: File of Factory;
    I: Integer;
    IsCorrect: boolean;
    Records: AoW;
begin
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
        SetLength(Records, 4);
        IsCorrect := True;
        AssignFile(TypeFile, OpenDialog1.FileName);
        Reset(TypeFile);
        I := 0;
        while not(Eof(TypeFile)) do
        begin
            Read(TypeFile, Records[I]);
            Inc(I);
        end;
        CloseFile(TypeFile);
    end;
    for I := 1 to SpinEditOfWorkers.Value do
    begin
        MainStringGrid.Cells[1, I] := Records[I-1].Name;
        MainStringGrid.Cells[2, I] := IntToStr(Records[I-1].DetailsOnMonday);
        MainStringGrid.Cells[3, I] := IntToStr(Records[I-1].DetailsOnTuesday);
        MainStringGrid.Cells[4, I] := IntToStr(Records[I-1].DetailsOnWednesday);
        MainStringGrid.Cells[5, I] := IntToStr(Records[I-1].DetailsOnThursday);
        MainStringGrid.Cells[6, I] := IntToStr(Records[I-1].DetailsOnFriday);
        MainStringGrid.Cells[7, I] := IntToStr(Records[I-1].DetailsOnSaturday);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: вы уверены что "типизированный файл" и "текстовый файл каждое значение на новой строчке" это одно и то же?

Comment: `TStringList` для загрузки текстового файла, и читайте по строкам

Comment: TStringList нет в делфи

Comment: он там со времен диназвров есть, ищите лучше

Comment: Вбейте в поиск и проверьте сами. Вопрос вообще был не об этом.

Comment: проблема в том, что вы сами не знаете о чем ваш вопрос. Типизированный файл и текстовый файл по строкам это разные вещи. Вам сказано как прочитать текстовый и какой класс для этого использовать. Если вы юзаете не версию делфи из прошлого тысячелетия, то TStringList там имеется.

Comment: Вы правы, я не до конца понимаю отличия типизированного файла от текстового, но я надеялся что мне помогут разобраться с этой темой, так как она не особо гуглится. Мне нужно прочитать именно массив записей и именно из типизированного файла. Текстовый не может быть типизированным?

Comment: нет. в типизированный файл это бинарная последовательность байтов. Запись должна иметь фиксированную длину, и строки должны испоьзоваться фиксированной длины. там нет никаких рзаделителей (а-ля переносов строк) между полями, все основано на рзамере самой записи, ее полей и смещениями полей относительно начала. Фактически руками вы не создадите типизированный файл, его сначала надо записать программно.

Comment: А если моя программа должна предлагать выбрать пользователю файл, с которого будет загружена таблица? Пользователь сможет выбрать только файл, созданный моей программой ранее?

Comment: в принципе да. Но по сути не обязательно в вашей программе. Можно файл создать и в другой, но при этом должна использоваться одна и та же структура данных.

Comment: [почитать](http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/viewitem.asp?catalogid=843)

Answer (score 2):

Файл с данными надо читать зеркально относительно того, как эти данные в файл писались.

> В текстовом файле данные находятся каждое значение на новой строчке.

Это не похоже на `File of Record`. Читайте каждую строчку отдельно.